# Clusters for production environment

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[image: Sandbox cluster]

When I create the cluster it shows sandbox. How to create the cluster for production environment?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a free M0 Sandbox which meant for testing, not production environments.

M0 Sandbox is a Shared Clusters

> For teams learning MongoDB or developing small applications. Get 512MB storage free and scale up to 5GB.

[image]

Comment: I dont see any option that is for production

Comment: @AashishNagar what type of traffic and database size you're expecting. According to that, you can pick any tier starting from`M10` which is a Dedicated cluster.

Comment: Starting fro `M30` is good for high-end production environments https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/upgrading-your-free-mongodb-atlas-database-to-production-ready-instances